# mysql get rows that doesn't exist on a given criteria relative to another value

Tags: mysql

i have a table like following:

```
+-----+-------+
| uid | value |
+-----+-------+
| 104 |   L   |
| 104 |   M   |
| 104 |   N   |
| 103 |   Q   |
| 101 |   N   |
| 102 |   L   |
+-----+-------+
```

now what i am looking for is get the values of 104 and the compare it to other uid and return value if only not found, like following:

```
+-----+-------+
| uid | value |
+-----+-------+
| 101 |   L   |
| 101 |   M   |
| 102 |   M   |
| 102 |   N   |
| 103 |   L   |
| 103 |   M   |
| 103 |   N   |
+-----+-------+
```

here, 104 got L, M, and N, so i'm looking for values of other uid's which doesn't have L, M or N (values relative to 104), please note, 103 got Q, but since it's not in 104, and i'm trying to compare with 104, Q is not relevant here,  how to get that in mysql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following query based on `CROSS JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT finalTable.uid,
finalTable.`value`
FROM 
(SELECT
    YOUR_TABLE.uid,
    t.`value`
FROM    YOUR_TABLE
CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM YOUR_TABLE
        WHERE   uid = 104
    ) t
WHERE   YOUR_TABLE.uid != 104
AND t.`value`   <> YOUR_TABLE.`value`
) finalTable 
LEFT JOIN YOUR_TABLE ON YOUR_TABLE.uid = finalTable.uid AND YOUR_TABLE.`value` = finalTable.`value`
WHERE YOUR_TABLE.uid IS NULL
ORDER BY finalTable.uid;
```

See [**Demo Here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4305/2/0)

Comment: There seems to be far more query here than is strictly necessary

Comment: I was thinking the same. But the way I approached is kind of `incremental approach`. That's why I couldn't omit / lessen anything. Any idea to do it better from your side? I really appreciate that! @strawberry

Comment: what does the left join part do? the sql seems working without it, will it effect something if data volume increases?

Comment: `will it effect something if data volume increases?` **YES**. Without the `left join` you might get those records which actually exist in your table. The `LEFT JOIN` part is responsible for removing those entries which already exist in your table. By doing so you will get only those rows which don't exist.@Pingukutu

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.uid
           FROM my_table a
           LEFT 
           JOIN my_table b
             ON b.value <> a.value
            AND b.uid = 104
          WHERE a.uid <> 104
            AND b.uid IS NULL
```

Or something like that

Comment: Pardon me if am wrong. But I don't think this solution works for the `original post`. The `OP` asks for those rows which don't exist [`based on particular condition`].